# How to identify item values in pl/sql content after page submission?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created a page containing a pl/sql content region where I have created an html table. The pl/sql code to create the table and screenshot of the table is given.

The page is the 2nd page in a wizard list of total of 4 pages. So when the "Finish" button on 4th page is clicked I want to insert all the rows of this html table into a database table.

I want to know how to identify the values put in the html table and how to insert these values in a database table. Could anyone help me do this?

```
BEGIN
  htp.p('
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE>Organization Records</TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <H1>Organization Records</H1>
            <TABLE id="DataForm" BORDER="1 " style="border-collapse: collapse; width="100%">
                <TR style="width=50%">
                    <TH>Hierarchy</TH>
                    <TH>Org Long Name</TH>
                </TR>
                <TR style="width=50%">
                    <TH><input type="text"/></TH>
                    <TH>
                        <select id="S1" name="S1">
                            <option value="id1">data1</option>
                            <option value="id2">data2</option>
                            <option value="id3">data3</option>
                        </select>
                    </TH>
                 </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add</button>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

');
end;

[image: pl/sql content]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to capture the values when page 2 is submitted, because they are no longer present in the HTML by the time you submit page 4.

Change the `name` attribute of the `select` to one that APEX allows - i.e. one of "f01", "f02", ..., "f50".  (See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_app.htm#AEAPI215) for details.)

When the page is submitted, APEX will then populate a corresponding array e.g. `apex_application.g_f01`, `apex_application.g_f02`, etc.

So all you need to do is loop through the relevant array to get the values and insert them into your table:

```
for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop
   insert into mytable (value) values (apex_application.g_f01(i));
end loop;
```

Comment: Tony, first and foremost.. I admire your work here! What are your thoughts about leveraging an apex collection in this case?

Comment: @hisnameismyname2 thank you!  Yes I would prefer to use an APEX collection rather than inserting directly into the database table because it means you can decide whether the insert into the database table is needed at the end of the wizard (page 4 here) rather than inserting rows half-way through the wizard that could need to be deleted at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't understand why you fall in the trap of writing your own HTML. You're doing yourself and APEX a disservice.
With what you've provided you have demonstrated no use at all for a block of plsql nor the need to generate your own HTML. You are even running into the problem of having to map the items from the page to the backend.
I'll go even further and say that what you are putting out will create completely invalid HTML in your page, and the only reason that it works is because YOUR browser (which may not be the target audience's) is so forgivingly parsing it anyway. (the tag HTML is a root tag and may only occur once. So here you've stacked an HTML document within an HTML document. Check your page source and run it through a validator).

Why, or what reason, do you have not to use the tried and proven method of using a classic report in conjuction with the [apex_item](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192) api? Or, why not use a tabular form, which can provide validation and per-row processing? Either way is declarative and fast.
With the classic report, all I need is a classic report region and some SQL, and I'll be much faster at putting out the same thing you've written here.

```
select apex_item.text(p_idx => 1, p_value => text_value) hierarchy
     , apex_item.select_list_from_query(p_idx => 2, p_value => org_id, p_query => 'select dname, depto from dept') org_name
from my_table
```

It'd be even shorter when using a tabular form as I don't have to put out the html. (and consider apex 5.1's interactive grid...)

Also, you may want to consider using [apex_collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531) to map your data to, seeing as this is a wizard. If you don't you will be mapping data directly onto tables which is usually not the desired method while in a wizard. Furthermore, what if processing or validation errors occur? Entered data in the tabular form (self-created or otherwise) will not be stored upon errors, causing the form to be cleared/reset as the page is re-rendered.

Unless you have a real damn good reason to generate your own, custom html in apex, which cannot be captured in a template (page, region, report, html expression), don't do it. Consider twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on a custom form, and in combined querys the tabular form is useless, so you have to write your own proccess to it.

As Tony said, you can set values in the `apex_application.g_f01` to `apex_application.g_f50` array which can be set in the `p_idx` parameter.

For example: `APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(1,empno)`

See also (in the Hidden example it explains more detailful): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI196